# Function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and connection subset

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to figure it out for a really long time. Does there exist a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ that while  $ f \le 1 $ there is infinitely many connected components and at the same time $ f < 1 $ is connected.

Comment: Yes: such a function exists, and you can construct it in such a way that it satisfies the condition you need

Comment: So we want $f^{-1}(-\infty,1]$ to have infinitely many components, while $f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$ is connected?

Comment: @zhw. yes, that's the function I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following sets:
$$H = \{ (x,y) : y<0\}$$
$$S= \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{ (x,y): |y-n| < 1/3  \ \ ; \ \ |x| <1\}$$

Here is a sketch of the two sets. Note that $S$ is made by infinitely many disjoint rectangles.

[image]

Now define $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$
$$f(p)=\begin{cases}0 & \mbox{ if } p \in H \\ 1 & \mbox{ if } p  \in S \\ 2 & \mbox{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
$\{ f \le 1\} = H \cup S$ has infinitely many disjoint components.

$\{ f < 1\} = H$ is connected.

Comment: thanx a lot for that! looks good

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(0,0)=1/2,$ $f(n,0)=1, n=1,2\dots,$ and $f=2$ everywhere else. Then $f^{-1}(-\infty,1) = \{(0,0)\}$ and $f^{-1}(-\infty,1]$ $ = \{(n,0):n=0,1,\dots\}.$